# How to use DBpedia to identify the topics

Tags: nlp, wikidata, linked-data, ontology, dbpedia

In the paper "[Discovering Relevant Topics using DBPedia providing non-obvious recommendations](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2052352&dl=ACM&coll=DL)" they have used skos:broader property and dcterms:subject property.

In my task given the word I want to identify the topic of it. For example, given the word; 'suport vector machine', I want to identify topics from it such as classification algorithm, machine learning etc.

However, I could not find the properties mentioned in the paper (skos:broader and dcterms:subject) in the relevant DBpedia pages: http://dbpedia.org/page/Support_vector_machine

Please let me know how I can achieve my task (retrieving topics from keywords) using DBpedia properties (or using any other knowledgebase)?

I am happy to provide more examples if needed.

Comment: Look at http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Support_vector_machines

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thank you very much. However, I am wondering why some keywords does not have a category page, even though a Wikipedia page exists for them. E.g., http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Recurrent_neural_network. Please let me know why this happens?

Comment: Perhaps the topic is too narrow and respective category is not created in Wikipedia. There are http://dbpedia.org/page/Recurrent_neural_network and http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Artificial_neural_networks. Pages and categories are different things in Wikipedia. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Category

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thanks alot for the great explanation. I am just wondering if I can build a topic hierarchy using `page` and `category` details. For example, Machine Learning (Level 1) -> Artificial Neural Network (Level 2) -> Recurrent neural Network (Level 3). Since, I am new to DBpedia, I'm not sure what information I should use in `page` and `category` to do this. Please let me know if you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Probably `skos:broader` on categories pages and `dct:subject` on regular pages. Perhaps you will be interested in DBpedia Spotlight.

Comment: @StanislavKralin Many thanks for the recommendation :) I am currently implementing this. However, sometimes I am bit confused as how to build a topic hierarchy as I am getting more than 5 subject and many broader property. Is there a way to measure strength or something and reduce the additional URIs?

Comment: I think it is possible to figure out something, but probably you should ask a separate question, most likely, on SO.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I posted a question in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848040/how-to-use-dbpedia-properties-to-build-a-topic-hierarchy Please let me know if you have any ideas and suggestions :)

Comment: it seems there are two questions there. 1. How to limit the number of DBpedia Spotlight results. 2. How to limit the number of subjects and categories for a particular result. As for the second question, please paste you current query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I updated my question according to your suggestions :) Please kindly let me know if you have any interesting ideas.