# How to extract DBpedia infomation

Tags: uses-of-open-data, linked-data, rdf, ontology, dbpedia

I wrote a python programme to extract the DBpedia links for a given document using DBpedia Spotlight. Now I am interested in getting the **skos:broader property and dcterms:subject property** for each DBpedia link. Is there any DBpedia API that I can use for this?

I am happy to provide any examples if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here below I'm using examples from comments to your [previous question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/12518/16193).

**Linked Data Fragments**

For simple queries, you could use Linked Data Fragments:

- [Query 1](http://fragments.dbpedia.org/2016-04/en?subject=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FRecurrent_neural_network&predicate=http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fsubject&object=)
- [Query 2](http://fragments.dbpedia.org/2016-04/en?subject=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3AArtificial_neural_networks&predicate=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23broader&object=)

Add `Accept: application/json` header, if you need a JSON  response.

**SPARQL**

For complex queries, you could use SPARQL.

For example, you don't need to know preliminarily, whether a resource is a Wikipedia category or not:

- [Query 1](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+%3Fresource+%3Fbroader+%3Fsubject+WHERE+%7B%0D%0AVALUES+(%3Fresource)+%7B+(dbr%3ARecurrent_neural_network)%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++++(dbc%3AArtificial_neural_networks)+%7D%0D%0A%7B%3Fresource+skos%3Abroader+%3Fbroader+%7D%0D%0AUNION%0D%0A%7B%3Fresource+dct%3Asubject+%3Fsubject+%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+)
- [Query 2](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+%3Fresource+%3Fproperty+%3Fobject+WHERE+%7B%0D%0AVALUES+(%3Fresource)+%7B+(dbr%3ARecurrent_neural_network)%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++++(dbc%3AArtificial_neural_networks)+%7D%0D%0AVALUES+(%3Fproperty)+%7B+(dct%3Asubject)+(skos%3Abroader)+%7D%0D%0A%3Fresource+%3Fproperty+%3Fobject+%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+)

You can perform even more advanced queries with SPARQL 1.1 [property paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths).

[SPARQLWrapper](https://rdflib.github.io/sparqlwrapper/) is a Python library for working with SPARQL endpoints.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. Can we directly use the DBpedia URL in the SPARQL query. For example given the DBpedia link http://dbpedia.org/page/Support_vector_machine can we get the `broader` and `subject` properties using SPARQL?

Comment: what I am not sure of is how to get the values for `dbr` and '`dbc`. For example if we consider 'Support Vector Machine' the `dbr` needs to be `Support vector machine` - singular, whereas `dbc` needs to be `Support vector machines` - plural. Please let me know if we can resolve this by directly using the DBpedia URL given by DBpedia Spotlight?

Comment: You can use full URIs directly, like [this](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?query=SELECT+*+WHERE+{+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FSupport_vector_machine%3E+skos%3Abroader|dct%3Asubject+%3Fo+}&format=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson). I'm not sure that DBpedia Spotlight searches in DBpedia categories.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you have mentioned DBpedia Spotlight only provides the URIs for `DBpedia resource pages`. Is there any other way to recognise the DBpedia category pages?

Comment: @JCena, Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with. I suppose there exist respective reqular entities for the majority of categories.